# Editing local jsbin

Tags: javascript

I have a local version of jsbin that I want to be able to style as the font are much larger than the version online. Does anyone know where I can find these files, if they are available on my computer, so that I can adjust the font size?

Thank you,

Rob

Comment: Try Stylish for FF or Chrome and apply your own style to `pre` and `code`.

Comment: So is there no way to change this for good so each time I start it I won't have to go through this process?

Comment: Yes, with Stylish you can do this. Just go here and try it https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the web console and put in...

jsbin.settings.font = 12;

...or whatever font size you want! Default is 14.
Check out the docs on CodeMirror; they helped me a lot with this.
http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#config